# Google Tag Manager for One main Domain

Tags: google-tag-manager

Im using Google analytic + Google Tag Manager.

My website have some versions of web: .dev (for development), .com (for public).

Code on two sites are the same. But when I make a purchase in .dev then data was collected to Google analytic too.

How can I config for GA only collect data in .com domain?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a rule (trigger) with {{url hostname}} equals yourdomain.com condition to fire your Google Analytics tag.

Comment: Thank you, i saw that, when i add two rule (all page & domain), its seem use "or" condition. Then i combine two conditions in one rule, that ok.